# today's records fetching from linq to sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, linq-to-sql

i want to fetch records of todays from my table. 
I written following query -

```
public ICollection<DashboardNotification> GetNotificationOfToday()
        {
            DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime yesterdaysDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            db = new BobTheBuilderEntities();
            var notificationList = (from n in db.DashboardNotifications.OrderByDescending(n => n.NotificationDateTime)
                                    where (n.NotificationDateTime > yesterdaysDate && n.NotificationDateTime <= todaysDate)
                                    select n).ToList();

            return notificationList;
        }
```

[image]

But above query is not working, cause it fetching records from yesterday too.

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Is your condition correct ? (n.NotificationDateTime > yesterdaysDate && n.NotificationDateTime <= todaysDate). First you are checking that the NotificationDateTime should be greater then yesterday (which means today) and then you are checking that NotificationDateTime should be LESS than Equal to Today's date ?

Comment: @Behroz : at initially i checked only today's date but it is not working then i googled and then i come to know that i have to compare it with two dates then only i'll get result that's why i added yesterday's date for comparison .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
var notificationList = (from n in db.DashboardNotifications.OrderByDescending(n => n.NotificationDateTime)
                                    where (n.NotificationDateTime > yesterdaysDate )
                                    select n).ToList();
```

Comment: Its not working at all showing error that linq to entities does not support AddDays(-1) function.. like that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try declaring yesterdays date as a variable first

```
var yesterDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var notificationList = (from n in db.DashboardNotifications.OrderByDescending(n => n.NotificationDateTime)
                        where (n.NotificationDateTime > yesterDay)
                        select n).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry @Behroz, I didnt see your edited answer before posting mine.. apologies for that